# Using a JS framework for developing a database client application?

Tags: javascript, database, web-services

Requirement:Using a JS frameworks and readily available UI elements to develop a database application (which would connect to databases the user wants to connect to using jdbc, and do some drag-and-drop SQL query building etc. and similar functionality)

I understand that I would need some parts of it needs to be residing in a web server. Since not all the users' databases (local, intranet) could be accessible from a central server where I run my application, I am thinking I would need to bundle the server also (apache tomcat) with my application. Is there any simpler tools/methods to architect this, keeping the UI in HTML5/JS?

Comment: The specification _"connect to any database the user wants to connect to"_ seems a bit too broad. I would suggest node.js. Have a look at the [drivers already available](http://nodejsdb.org/db-mysql/). For the HTML part any framework would do the job.

Comment: thanks, yes the tool being a DB client the connectivity aspect will remain broad atleast covering major databses

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not mention any limitations on the technology or framework to be used, see if you can use this.

```
MEAN -- MongoDB, Express, Angular and Node.
http://mean.io/#!/
```